# Can you run the same vb.net form more than once?

Tags: vb.net, forms

Is it possible to run the same form more than once?

`Run form1`

Press `button1` saves the information of `form1` in variables and re-opens `form1` for new input.

Comment: The form should not disappear after you press save unless you are closing it explicitly or exiting the program. What you should do after the save is to reset the input fields, that is all. Show us your save code.

Comment: Yes, it is possible.  But what not just clear all the input fields?

Answer (score 3):

It's probably easier to create a new instance of the form than to try to accurately clear/reset fields and other data.

Forms are just classes. You can create and show as many instances of the from class as you want, just like any other class:  5,  5000, or as many as your computer has the ability to handle.

Of course, you'll still need to write code to save data from the previous instance, and there's a lot left unsaid in the question about how things are laid out right now in terms of where button1 is and what you want to happen in the transition.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned above, a form is nothing but a class. You can create as many instances as you need. after all this is Windows. So if you have a form with a button that opens the form you simple place the snippet below in the form click event `

```
Dim frm as theformname    
frm.showdialog`
```